# PowerBI Embed in Angular 7 gives ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR

Tags: angular, powerbi

Hi I have Embed PowerBI in Angular Using an NPM library (ngx-powerbi)

Most of the times the implementation works as expected. However sometime it gives ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR

[image]

I have added the code to initialize the PowerBI report in

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
     this.powerBiService = new NgxPowerBiService();
     this.powerBIAccessToken = localStorage.getItem('PowerBIAadToken');
     this.pbiContainerElement = <HTMLElement>(document.getElementById('powerbi-container'));
     this.getReport();
} 



getReport(embedToken) {
        this.config = {
            type: 'report',
            id: this.setting.reportId,
            tokenType: models.TokenType.Aad,
            embedUrl: this.setting.embedUrl,
            accessToken: embedToken,
            settings: {
                filterPaneEnabled: this.filterPaneEnabled,
                navContentPaneEnabled: this.navContentPaneEnabled
            }
        };

        this.report = this.powerBiService.embed(this.pbiContainerElement, this.config);
    }
```

In the Html I have:
"`<div id="powerbi-container" class="power-bi-container"></div>`"

Since its an intermittent issue, hard time find a root cause for this

Comment: You are getting the access token from the local storage (`localStorage.getItem('PowerBIAadToken')`). How do you acquired this? When it was saved there?

Comment: There is a logic to check if its exist and or expired, in those cases I have an API to get the token and this variable